# Scala Reflect Case Class Apply Method Runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, runtime

How do you reflect a case class's members at run time without an instance?

For example if I have the following case class:

```
package com.abc

object Holder {
  case class Hello(message:String,count:Int)
}
```

I would of thought although I don't have an instance of Hello to reflect I could reflect the Companion Object apply method and inspect the arguments to know about what members it has?

```
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val module = mirror.staticModule("com.abc.Holder$Hello")
val instance = mirror.reflectModule(module).symbol.typeSignature.member(TermName("apply")).asMethod.paramLists
instance.foreach(println)
```

However this returns "none" is not a method. So it doesn't have an apply method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the below conclusion. Is there any way to use Scala reflection instead of Class.forName?

```
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val classSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(Class.forName("com.quantexa.anonymizer.FiuModel$Customer"))
val classApply = classSymbol.companion.typeSignature.member(TermName("apply")).asMethod

val members = classApply.paramLists.flatten.map(x => (x.asTerm.name,x.typeSignature))
```